# How to change default elasticsearch password in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Elasticsearch's [official docker image documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) provides this `docker-compose.yml` example:

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.3
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.3
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

However, it doesn't explain how to customize the password. It does direct us to a [X-Pack documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.6/security-getting-started.html), but I refuse to believe I have to go through all that trouble just to change a password. Is there any simpler, canonical way of configuring a custom password for elasticsearch on a Docker Compose file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from 6.0 elasticsearch docker images has the ability to configure the password using the following environment variable - ELASTIC_PASSWORD.
For example:
docker run -e ELASTIC_PASSWORD=MagicWord docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.1.3
See:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/docker.html

Comment: Did they delete it? Because I don't see this variable in the new docs for 6.x?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/docker.html

Comment: Just FYI, I've confirmed that setting the env variable ELASTIC_PASSWORD works in elasticsearch:7.9.1

Comment: It looks like ELASTIC_PASSWORD variable is supported only in platinum version of the docker image: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/docker.html#_image_types